# C# SMTP issue "Client was not authenticated"

Tags: c#, email, authentication

I'm currently running into an issue that my code fails to authenticate against an Exchange server, where it runs fine with gmail.

Here's my code

```
client = new SmtpClient(smtp_server, smtp_port); //webmail.airbaltic.com
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = smpt_enableSSL;
client.Timeout = 60 * 5 * 1000;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(smtp_domain))
{
   client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtp_user, smtp_password);
}
else
   client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtp_user, smtp_password, smtp_domain);

try
{
    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(mail_from, message.recep))
    {
       mail.Subject = mail_title;
       mail.Body = message.message;
       if (message.attachedFile != null)
             mail.Attachments.Add(message.attachedFile);

       client.Send(mail);
       if (message.attachedFile != null)
            message.attachedFile.Dispose();
       }

}
catch (Exception e)
{
      Debug.LogError(e);
}
```

And the response I'm getting back from the server is "530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated". I've quintuple checked the password and username, as well as the domain and server adress, scoured the forums, even tried the same configuration from an external mail client (where it works), and nothing.

The server itself doesn't use SSL and uses NTLM for authentication.

EDIT:
Looking into this further (i.e. checking sent and recieved packets), it seems like the client I used for testing the username and password does authentication first, while SmtpClient.send() seems to skip it for some reason

Comment: Try setting `UseDefaultCredentials` to `true` real quick.  See if that resolves it.  Is there a reason you have it set to `false`?

Comment: because he wants to use specific ones at a guess..

Comment: Yeah.. [but aren't unique logons expecting authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx) or am I reading this wrong?  EDIT: i.e.: I'd be surprised to hear that `smtp_password` is being hashed/salted/mucked with.  I'm betting it's just set to a cleartext value.  If it *is*, we're not going to be much help.

Comment: smtp_password is in cleartext, yes. And, if I'm reading it correctly, UseDefaultCredentials and client.credentials are used for authentication if the server requires it. If none of them are set, only then it sends it anonymously

Comment: Your Exchange server doesn't require authentication?  Have you tried `true`, yet?  This isn't impossible.. but it seems.. unusual.  Contradictory.

Comment: It does require authentication. Just not from the default credentials

Comment: Then your Exchange server is likely expecting a **non cleartext** authentication.  Since you've confirmed that you're sending cleartext only, it's likely not going to work without passing what is expected.

Comment: Maybe impersonate the given user and then run the mail command?

Comment: Upon further inspection and a bit of WireShark action, it seems like the code isn't sending an Auth command to the server before starting a message, which returns the Client not Authenticated error